# How can I force Windows Server 2003 to restart?

Tags: windows-server-2003

So I'm logged onto a remote desktop session as Administrator. The CPU usage is pegged at 50% with the csrss.exe process running under the Console session as the culprit.

I can't log off the Console user from the Task Manager and I can't restart using "shutdown /r /f"

Is there any way I can force the server to restart or kill the Console session? There is no one else logged on to the server right now and I don't have physical access to reset it. Explorer is barely responsive but the task manager and command line and working fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem once and can't recall a happy ending. I think I used process explorer to try and kill every possible process and thing i could find on the console. Eventually I froze the box and had to get the data center tech to restart the box :-( good luck.  And it hasn't happened since

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `taskkill.exe /pid <pid> /f` for the CSRSS.EXE process?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but nothing appears to happen after issuing the command.

Comment: Does the server have any "out of band" management interface, like HP iLO or Dell Drac?

Answer (score -1):

If you have RPC access to the machine (e.g. not firewalled),  you can [run Shutdown.exe remotely.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317371)

```
shutdown \\remotehost /r
```

(Also, for reasons I've never understood, nltest.exe also has a remote shutdown option built into it, but not a reboot command.)

Comment: Questions mentions `shutdown /r /f` doesn't work.

Comment: [shutdown /r /f] specified by OP is the syntax as issued from a local cmd session. [shutdown \\remotehost] is issued from a remote host, and uses RPC to connect to the machine in question over the network, potentially circumventing whatever is hanging the console session.  CPU pegged at 50% tells me one of two cores is busy with misbehaving software, leaving one free; OP still may be able to administer system from someplace other than logged into a desktop session.

Comment: that worked for me
open CMD on server and type: shutdown -r -f